# Why does Ubuntu install incompatible versions of Seamonkey?

Tags: browser

Seamonkey (Netscape) 2.0.13 does not work with Ubuntu. Ubuntu keeps installing it. The system won't allow 2.0.14. Version 2.1 has been installable but are no longer Netscape nor are file compatible. Manual installs fail.

2.0.8, 11, 14 are good. 2.0.13 or 2.1 & later are either incompatible with the system or files. What does it take to make the last true version of Netscape (Seamonkey 2.0.14) available?

Answer (score 3):

What version of Ubuntu are you using ? My guess is natty.

You can install other version of Seamonkey from a ppa

https://launchpad.net/~joe-nationnet/+ppa-packages

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:joe-nationnet/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install seamonkey
```

If you have a problem with the older version in the repos you should probably file a bug report.

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

I am building my own packages, available at [PPA's launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~bratherlui/+archive/seamonkey).

and I am trying to keep it up to date.